# Java Timer is waiting for Task to finish before next Task starts

Tags: java, asynchronous, timer

I have this simple application

```
package testy;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import static testy.Test.log;

public class Test {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    log("tasks start");
    timer.schedule(new Task1(), 1,120000);
    timer.schedule(new Task2(), 3000,120000);
    timer.schedule(new Task3(), 6000,120000);

    Thread.sleep(99999999L);
}

static void  log(String text) {
    System.out.println(text);
}
}

class Task1 extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        log("Task1 start");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(12000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            log("interupted");
        }
        log("Task1 end");
    }
}

class Task2 extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        log("Task2 start");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(12000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            log("interupted");
        }
        log("Task2 end");
    }
}

class Task3 extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        log("Task3 start");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(12000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            log("interupted");
        }
        log("Task3 end");
    }
}
```

From this code I expect that Task1 will be fired immediately and Task2 will be fired after 3 seconds (as delay time says). But what happens is Task2 is waiting for Task1 to finish and is fired immediately after that. LOG:

```
tasks start
Task1 start
Task1 end
Task2 start
Task2 end
Task3 start
Task3 end
Task1 start
Task1 end
Task2 start
Task2 end
Task3 start
Task3 end
```

As I understand Java Timer, Tasks should be fired independantly. Why then behaviour of this app is diffrent? How to achive starting Tasks precisily at the given time, without caring if Timer1 is finished?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html):

> Corresponding to each Timer object is a single background thread that is used to execute all of the timer's tasks, sequentially.

If you want the behaviour you describe using `Timer`, you would need multiple `Timer` instances.

Comment: I see I got Timer idea wrong then. Marking this as an answer, because of doc quoting. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

`Timer` uses a single thread. When you call `Thread.sleep(12000L);`, this thread is blocked and unable to execute other tasks. Try using a `ScheduledExecutorService` implementation instead to use a bigger pool of threads. You can create a simple thread pool with this:

```
java.util.concurrent.Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(corePoolSize)
```